# How can I get an entityform attached to an order in drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to append an entityform to an order in Drupal commerce. I included the several attempts in my code snippet. Version 1 just throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type EntityValueWrapper as array in /sites/all/modules/kalamuna/tb_commerce_panes/tb_commerce_panes.module on line 374
```

I tried two other attempts. Version 2 and 3 show up in $order, but when I get to the checkout page and var_dump $order it isn't there. Any ideas why?

```
function commerce_panes_custom_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  // Strip out the entityform type.
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  $entityform_type_name = $values['entityform_bundle'];

  // Create a new entityform from the remaining fields.
  global $user;
  $form = new Entityform(
    array(
      'type'     => $entityform_type_name,
      'created'  => time(),
      'changed'  => time(),
      'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
      'uid'      => 2
    )
  );

  // The process the rest entityform fields.
  foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
    if (strstr($k, 'field_')) {
      $form->$k = $v;
    }
  }

  //Version 1 - Original
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $order_wrapper->field_tb_registration_forms[] = $form;
  $order_wrapper->save();

  //Version 2 - Modified Original
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $node = $order_wrapper->values();
  $node->field_tb_registration_forms[] = $form;
  $order_wrapper->save();

  //Version 3 - modify $order and save it
  $order->field_tb_registration_forms = $form;
  commerce_order_save($order);

}
```

Comment: What type of field is >field_tb_registration_forms?

Comment: That was it! it was a text field. I ended up just storing the entityform_id in that field and changed calls to the form with:

    $reg_form_id = $order_wrapper->field_tb_registration_forms->value();
    $tb_registration_forms = entityform_load($reg_form_id);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first checking to make sure $order is set? If not then load cart from $user->id first and then wrap it.

Comment: Yes, I checked before and after adding forms. I even tried reloading the $order using commerce_order_load().